# Bloquear arquivos para que apenas usuários logados tenham acesso

Tags: php, pdf, download

Tenho uma estrutura de pasta montada da seguinte forma:

Sistema
 - dados
 - css
 - connections (banco de dados)
 - imagens

Na pasta dados disponibilizo os arquivos para os usuários autenticados fazer o download. Porém, se eu colocar na barra de endereço, por exemplo, `www.meusite/sistema/dados/usuario1/documento1.pdf`, ele faz o download normalmente sem estar logado. já tentei fazer o bloqueio por `.htaccess`, mas ele bloqueia tudo e nem o usuário logado consegue fazer o download.

Como eu posso resolver esse problema, dando acesso apenas aos usuários logados?

Answer (score 0):

Ao consultar essa URL, você pode fazer uma validação se o usuário é válido e está logado. Caso sim, efetua o download. Caso não, redireciona para a página inicial ou algo do tipo.